# If $a<b$, the $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x) $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a monotone non-decreasing function real valued function on $\mathbb R$.

**To Prove**:If $a<b$,  the $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x) $

**PROOF**:If   $0<x<1$ then $f(x)=bx+(1-x)a$ which is a non decreasing function.

Now,$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) - \lim_{x\to b^-}(x) =ab+(1-a)a-b^2-(1-b)a=a^2-b^2\le0$
.Hence,$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to b^-}(x) $

I'm not getting how to prove it for $(0,1)^c$.

Comment: This is now how you prove it. Start by the given inequality and then use monotonicity.

Comment: You've taken a particular example..It is not proof in $(0,1)$ .

Comment: @S717717:I also tried it using the $\epsilon - \delta $ definition for one-sided limits but that is also not working.

Comment: I can't follow the first line of your proof: $$\text{"If }0\lt x\lt1\text{ then }f(x)=bx+(1-x)a\text{"}$$ How does the equation $f(x)=bx+(-x)a$ follow from $0\lt x\lt1$??

Comment: @bof:It is the equation of a  line-segment with $a$ and $b$ as end points.

Comment: But all we know about $f$ is that it's a monotone non-decreasing real valued function; how do you conclude from that, that the graph of $f$ is a straight line??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - You cannot prove *true* a general statement by just trying out an example.
> - You can prove *false* a general statement by showing an example where the statement doesn't hold.

The statement you need to prove has several parts. First, you have to show that both
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)
$$
exist and then that the former is less than or equal to the latter.

For the existence, the hint is to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x):x>a\}
$$
and similarly for the other one.

> Let $l=\inf\{f(x):x>a\}$ and take $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $x_0>a$ with $f(x_0)<l+\varepsilon$. Let $\delta=x_0-a$. Since $f$ is nondecreasing, for $a<x<x_0=a+\delta$, it holds $0\le f(x)-l<\varepsilon$.

Next you want to show that
$$
\inf\{f(x):x>a\}\le\sup\{f(x):x<b\}
$$
Hint: $f(a)\le f(m)\le f(b)$, where $m=(a+b)/2$.

Comment: Good that you added the part of about existence of limits. I had assumed that OP is familiar with  their existence. +1

Comment: @egreg. Would you like to prove rigorously that the limits exist? I do not think the proof is trivial. There seem to be a few corners.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Probably you took a wrong path. You find the proof in the spoiler.

Comment: @egreg. Nice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way is contradiction. Assume the limits as $A, B$ and let $A>B$. Now we can choose an $x$ near $a$ and $x'$ near $b$ such that $a<x<x'<b$ and $f(x) $ is near $A$ and $f(x') $ is near $B$. Since $A>B$, it is possible to choose $x, x'$ such that $f(x) >f(x') $ and this contradicts that $f$ is non-decreasing.

If you prefer direct approach then choose $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and if $x, t$ are such that $a<x<c<t<b$ then $f(x) \leq f(c) \leq f(t) $. Now letting $x\to a^{+} $ and $t\to b^{-} $ we get the desired inequality. Note that this uses the result that limits preserve inequalities but weaken them.

Comment: @Parmanand Singh:$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x) \implies \lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) \le \lim_{k\to 0}f(b-k) \implies f(a) \le f(b)$.Using monotonicity,$a<b$.Is it correct?

Comment: @PKStyles: no the limits can't give any information about $f(a), f(b) $. Also you have to prove the inequality between limits so you can't start with the thing to be proved.

Comment: @PKStyles: also note that monotone non-decreasing means $a<b\Rightarrow f(a) \leq f(b) $ and not the other way round.